# What parts are new when the logic board is replaced by an Apple-certified shop?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, damage

I need to repair my logic board of my MacBook Pro due to a water spill - I cleaned it with isopropyl but couldn't get it to charge anymore (the indicator of the power supply doesn't turn on; probably a fault in the onewire circuit - so I'm guessing the motherboard).

However, I'm afraid to break it when trying to disassemble the logic board. So instead, I want to get it repaired. They told me it's about 450-500eur to get the logic board replaced.

Does that mean that it's an entirely new logic board? They won't put a refurbished one inside right? They are a very famous Apple-Certified shop so.. Also, I think the CPU is soldered on to it. So does that mean that in this cost, I get a new CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you don't know until the repair is complete.

Apple certified shops will enter case noted explaining to Apple what was done and you can ask the shop for a list of what components were replaced.

Apple supplies the parts, so Apple could have sent the repair shop an entirely new logic board or they could have shipped one that was refurbished / repaired / tested. You can't really know unless you physically inspect the part(s) in question.

Service parts are new and/or refurbished whether you have the repair done at the genius bar, Apple Repair mail in service or third party. It's the same pool of parts.

At 500 eu  - you are likely paying for the individual service part to be exchanged, configured and tested. I would ask about a flat rate repair - that would possibly reduce your initial cost and cover any/all issues and not just the main board.

If you can, get a second quote directly from Apple in your country:

- https://support.apple.com/mac-notebooks/repair/service

Comment: The sellers told me they would need to send the MacBook to the service center and they'll tell me what the cost would be to fix the device within 2 weeks -- is that what you mean by flat rate repair? I asked about the motherboard, since I think that that's where the problem is. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes - that sounds good. If they don't agree that the cost is fixed, they might suspect liquid damage. That's the only reason why the initial cost would be bumped up.  I would get a quite directly from Apple if you can in your country - https://support.apple.com/mac-notebooks/repair/service